# Capture SSL premaster key - Python Youtube-DL

Tags: python-3.x, wireshark, youtube-dl, tshark

I have a script in Python that is simply download some video with youtube-dl library.
**Please note: script is running in Anaconda Environment.**
On top of it I have a tshark capture all network traffic.
I'm looking for a way to capture and decode the SSL Pre Master key.
Is it possible to capture and save it in order to be re-used to decrypt traffic with WhireShark?

I'm using (in Anaconda env):
Python 3.6.5 - OpenSSL 1.1.1c  28 May 2019

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to capture SSL keys, you need to set the $SSLKEYLOGFILE environmental variable. I wrote an [article](https://tshark.dev/export/export_tls/) on using Firefox to download a website's HTML and then decrypting it. Other people have also written good articles on doing this:

- [SSL Decryption Guide: How to Decrypt SSL with Wireshark](https://www.comparitech.com/net-admin/decrypt-ssl-with-wireshark/): Covers all 3 major Operating Systems
- [Using Wireshark to Decode SSL/TLS Packets](https://packetpushers.net/using-wireshark-to-decode-ssltls-packets/): SSL decryption discussion by Packet Pushers

---

For youtube-dl to take advantage of the $SSLKEYLOGFILE variable, you need [Python 3.8 and OpenSSL 1.1.1](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/issues/11614).

Comment: Hello Jacobs, this works pretty fine for browsers, but I'm unable to capture any SSL Key log file from a Python Anaconda session using youtube-dl library.

Comment: Please add your python (`python -V`) and openssl version (`openssl version`) in your question.

Comment: Python 3.6.5 - OpenSSL 1.1.1c  28 May 2019

Comment: Looks like that's the problem (see edited response).

Comment: actually I did a mistake: I did not specify the file name in the $SSLKEYLOGFILE. your solution works also for Python 3.6.5 - OpenSSL 1.1.1c 28 May 2019.